# Import multiple txt datasets in R

Tags: r

I have a folder containing multiple txts, I want to import them as individual datasets, for example:

```
datasetpaths <- list.files("C:/OneDrive/R Resources/R Books/Mixed Effects Medels/ZuurDataMixedModelling", full.names = TRUE)
datasetnames <- list.files("C:/OneDrive/R Resources/R Books/Mixed Effects Medels/ZuurDataMixedModelling", full.names = FALSE)
datasetnames <- sub("\\..+", "", datasetnames, perl = TRUE)

datasetnames <- lapply(datasetpaths, FUN = read.table, header = TRUE, dec = ".")
```

But after doing this, I've got a list `datasetnames` containing multiple datasets. How can I import them individually, as individual variables, in one run?

Comment: The problem with importing them individually is that you have to come up with individual names for each of them - so you'd need to define each name and assign the data frame to it.  That means 1 run per file.  What is wrong with having them in a list?

Answer (score 0):

with `purrr::map`.

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- map_df(list.files("yourPath", full.names = TRUE), 
                 read.table, header = TRUE, dec = '.')
```

Comment: `map()` returns a list of datasets, it does the same thing as `lapply()`, I think.

Comment: use `map_df` - I've amended the answer

Comment: Also, if you need error handling, see this post: https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/398